# how do I prevent max-height transition from scrolling the page to the top?

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, css-transitions

I have a div with an original max-height of 0 to hide it initially, and with the tap of an anchor it's given a max height of 800px to reveal it. Basic stuff. However, anytime this transition occurs, it automatically scrolls the page to the top rather than leaving the page in whatever position it was in.

**Here is the html:**

```
<main class="outer-container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="text-container">
      <div class="text">

        <a class="reveal-hide" href="#">Show Hidden Div</a>

        <div class="hide">

         <!-- hidden div -->

        </div>
     </div>   
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

**and the css:**

```
.outer-container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
}
.wrapper {
  margin-top: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
.text-container {
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.hide {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.hide-is-showing {
  max-height: 1000px;
}
```

**and the jQuery:**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('.reveal-hide').on('click', function() {
        $(".hide").addClass("hide-is-showing");
      });

    });
```

So why is it scrolling to the top with every transition? and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try changing:

```
 <a class="reveal-hide" href="#">Show Hidden Div</a>
```

to:

```
<a class="reveal-hide" href="javascript:void(0)">Show Hidden Div</a>
```

because then it doesn't reload the page when you click on it.